# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$ divided by its non trivial ideal is isomorphic to?

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

I understand what an ideal is! Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$ is a field, it has two ideals, {0} and itself.

Non-trivial ideal of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$ itself.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$ divided by its non trivial ideal is isomorphic to singleton set {0 + $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$}.

However the answer was simply singleton {0}. Why was my answer wrong?

Comment: They are both singleton sets, both answers are right.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. The two answers are... isomorphic!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: It was {0} as well as {0 + I}

Comment: Then how could it happen that one if it now is wrong? This seems questionable, right?

Comment: Because it was a multiple choice question and the answer given was {0}

Comment: What I read so far was that it was to be isomorphic to {0 + I}

Comment: What were the other options in the multiple choice?

Comment: The multiple choice question didn't include {0 + $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{11})$}